# Arduino Serial Error

Tags: arduino

I am using Arduino ATmega2560. I have defined Serial as CONSOLE. When I am using CONSOLE it shows me error.

```c++
#include "Arduino.h"
#define CONSOLE Serial;

void setup()
{
    CONSOLE.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    CONSOLE.println("Hello");
    delay(2000);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors, it makes them impossible to search for

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question actually being asked is entirely about C++ and Arduino and not in any way about an IoT usage *of* an Arduino.  Hence this belongs on Stackoverflow or the Arduino site, not here.

Comment: Lose the semicolon - `#define CONSOLE Serial;` expands `Console.println()` to `Serial;.println()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this:

```c++
#define CONSOLE Serial;
```

To this:

```c++
#define CONSOLE Serial
```

Notice the absence of the `;` character in the change.

---

The preprocessor is expanding `CONSOLE` to `Serial;`, which results in, for example, `Serial;.begin(9600);`, which has 2 `;`s in the statement, the first of which is unwanted.